# POST data with urllib2 gives 400

Tags: python, postman

In the following code, when the following data(`template_data`) is passed in postman app on chrome then there is a response but the same data when posted with urllib2 gives an error, The only difference i notice is the `required` field i.e, `false should not be given in quotes even in postman script` else there is no response but the same fails in urllib2

If 'false' is given quotes in template_data even then the result is 400

Edit: In postman  false should not be given in quotes if gives gives an error, so not sure how to send this paramater

```
 import urllib
 import urllib2

 def get_url_data(url, request_method, content_type, data=None, 
                 headers={}):
    method = request_method
    handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    if data is not None:
        data = urllib.urlencode(data)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data=data,headers=headers)
    request.add_header("Content-Type", content_type)
    request.get_method = lambda: method
    try:
        connection = opener.open(request)
    except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
        connection = e
    print connection.code
    if connection.code == 200:
        resp = connection.read()
        return resp
    return None

form_template_url="https://example.com"
auth='sometokenid'
template_header_param = {'Authorization':auth}
template_data = {
  "templateName": "somename", 
  "category": "Handbook", 
  "formTemplateDef": [{
    "id": "0",
    "component": "textInput", 
    "editable": "true",
    "index": "0", 
    "label": "Handbook",
    "description": "", 
    "placeholder": "TextInput",
    "options": [], 
    "required": 'false'
   }]
}
template_response = get_url_data(form_template_url,
  'POST', 'application/json',
   template_data, template_header_param)
```

Comment: YEs it is defined please see the edit in code

Comment: please replace single quotes with double one i.e `"required": "false"` because json replace single with double

Comment: Yields 200 under Python2; seems like a Postman bug.

Comment: i think something error in url schema  because you aren't escaping a special chars please provide us with a url example

Comment: return `200` for me this is an  [image](http://imgur.com/a/pf34t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
```

and use

```
urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

This should work.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.